# Vb.net deserialize object in json

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, serialization

I don't know what to put above the variable to make deserialize the object and I can't find it anywhere...
(I don't want to use json.net)

here's the class code

```
<Serializable()> _
 Public Class O
<???????()> _
Private Likes As Decimal

Public Sub New(ByVal l As Decimal)
    Likes = l
End Sub
End Class
```

and here's the main code

```
Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(O))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resp))
    Dim o As O= CType(ser.ReadObject(ms), O)
    ms.Close()
    ms.Dispose()
```

So what should I put instead of ????

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the `Likes` member public.

```
Public Class O

    Public Likes As Decimal

    Public Sub New(ByVal l As Decimal)
        Likes = l
    End Sub

End Class
```